# $resource transformResponse not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Got a simplified `$resource` example here (adapted from Angular site):

```js
angular.module('project', ['mongolab']);

function ListCtrl($scope, Project) {
  $scope.projects = Project.test();
}

angular.module('mongolab', ['ngResource']).
factory('Project', function ($resource) {
  var url, dfParams, actions;

  url = 'https://api.mongolab.com/api/1/databases' + '/angularjs/collections/projects/:id';
  dfParams = {
    apiKey: '4f847ad3e4b08a2eed5f3b54'
  };

  actions = {
    test: {
      method: 'GET',
      isArray: true,
      transformResponse: function (response) {
        // line is never getting called
        console.log('transforming');
        return response;
      }
  };

  var Project = $resource(url, dfParams, actions);
  return Project;
});
```

**The question** is that the line `console.log('transforming')` is never getting called. Why is that? Everything else works fine.

Live fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/CaioToOn/b75g3/).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This functionality is only available in the 1.1.2 or later versions of AngularJs.  It is not available in the 1.1.1 or earlier versions of AngularJs.

Answer (score 2):

Response transformation callback is not exposed in $resource service. It lives inside the underlying $http service.

So you have two choices:

- Use "low-level" $http instead of $resource abstraction,
- Create some kind of wrapper around your resource, which would transform the response the way you want.

Comment: I thought that too (not exposed in `$resource`). But then I looked at `$resource`'s code and it's documented in the [source code](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ngResource/resource.js#L69-L74). Also, reading through the code, you see it extends the `httpConfig` and [passes to underlying `$http`](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ngResource/resource.js#L437-L447). And it seems to be intentional, as they [wrote a test case](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/test/ngResource/resourceSpec.js#L686-L705) for it.

Comment: You were looking at unstable master branch, which isn't yet released.

Comment: Yes, I got it by @rgaskill answer's. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue,and I use AngularJS 1.2.26.
I have defined a interceptor that contains a `transformResponse` of $http level like:

```
return {
  'request': function (config) {
      config.defaults.transformResponse = function(data){
          //some has been done
      };
      return config;
},
```

**when I DELETE the code above, my `transformResponse` in $resource worked!**
In order to solve this problem,I defined my `transformResponse` in $resource like:

```
return $resource(pathConfig.serverURL + ':demoId',
    {
        demoId: "@id"
    },
    {
        hello: {
            method: "GET",
            url: serverDomain + ":demoId",
            transformResponse: addTransformResponses(
                [
                    function (data, getHeaders) {
                        //doing hello's OWN interceptors
                    }
                ])
        }
    });
```

and `addTransformResponses` contains **common interceptor** like:

```
addTransformResponses: function (addTrans) {
    return [this.parseResponseJson, this.parseResponseArray]
        .concat(addTrans);
},

//parse JSON
parseResponseJson: function (data, getHeaders) {
    try {
        return angular.fromJson(data);
    } catch (e) {
        console && console.error("return data is not a JSON!");
        return data;
    }
},
parseResponseArray: function (data, getHeaders) {
    if (angular.isArray(data)) {
        return {"array": data};
    }
    return data;
}
```

by doing this, you can configure common interceptors and some request's own interceptors well! :)
If any practice better,please tell me! thanks!

Comment: Where exactly are you adding the `addTransformResponses`, `parseResponseJson` and `parseResponseArray` functions?