# Requesting Example for angular.js $http (or $resource) POST and transformRequest as a service

Tags: post, angularjs-service, angular-resource, angular-http

Using angular 1.1.5 and needing to pass urlencoded data to the backend. I've gotten this to work with solution from here:
[How can I post data as form data instead of a request payload?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11442632/how-can-i-make-angular-js-post-data-as-form-data-instead-of-a-request-payload)

```
$http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: url,
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
    transformRequest: function(obj) {
        var str = [];
        for(var p in obj)
        str.push(encodeURIComponent(p) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(obj[p]));
        return str.join("&");
    },
    data: xsrf
}).success(function () {});
```

I've embedded this into my controller with success, but the 'cleaner' way is to use a service, and $resource instead of the $http object.
It is possible to use transformRequest with $resource after 1.1.2 from this topic:
[$resource transformResponse not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15455387/resource-transformrequest-not-working)
but I cannot find any working examples. Can anyone provide an example of the above solution as a service object using $resource?

Answer (score 14):

### $RESOURCE EXAMPLE

For **csrf**, In a rails app you have to add `<%= csrf_meta_tags %>` in your header layout (if not there by default)

```js
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngResource']);
app.config(["$httpProvider", function(provider)
{
      provider.defaults.headers.common['X-CSRF-Token'] = $('meta[name=csrf-token]').attr('content');
}]);
```

**Here is a service object**

```js
app.factory('$folders', ['$resource', function($resource)
{
    return $resource('/folders/:id',
            { id: '@id' },
            {
              list: { method: 'GET' , isArray: true }, //same as query
              create: { method: 'POST' }, // same as save
              update: { method: 'PUT' }
              // DEFAULT IMPLEMENTATION OF $RESOURCE
              //   'get':    {method:'GET'},
              //   'save':   {method:'POST'},
              //   'query':  {method:'GET', isArray:true},
              //   'remove': {method:'DELETE'},
              //   'delete': {method:'DELETE'}
            });
}]);
```

**Here is an example into a controller**

```js
app.controller('projectController', ['$scope', '$folders', function($scope, $folders)
{
    $scope.folders = $folders.list();
}]);
```

`Folders.list()` will automatically do `GET /folders/` on the server and return the result(that should be json) as an object.

### Tip:

Directly after `$scope.folders = Folders.list();` in the controller, `$scope.folders` will be empty, it will be populated in time, when the response comes back from the server.

Simple examples with $http and $ressources
http://jsfiddle.net/jhsousa/aQ4XX/

### ABOUT THE FORM

**here is a form**

```haml
%form{'ng-submit' => 'create(item)', 'ng-controller' => 'projectController', 'ng-init' => 'item.orientation=1;'}
  %input{'ng-model'=>'item.folderName', :type => :text, :placeholder => 'Name', :name => 'folderName'}
  %textarea{'ng-model'=>'item.description', :placeholder => 'Description', :required=>true, :name => 'description'}
  %input{'ng-model'=>'item.orientation', :type=>'radio', :name=>'orientation', :value=>'1'}
  %input{'ng-model'=>'item.orientation', :type=>'radio', :name=>'orientation', :value=>'2'}
  %input{:type => :submit, :value => 'Create', :name => 'new-project'}
```

You'll notice the `ng-model`.
`'ng-model'=>'item.folderName'` will create a `$scope.item` in the `projectController` and add a key `folderName` in it. Same for the others `ng-model`'s.

`'ng-init'=>'item.orientation=1;'` is going to execute the expression. So it will do the following `item.orientation=1`, this way we set a default value for our radio inputs, so simple.

When the form is submitted `ng-submit` will catch it and call the `create` action from the `projectController` with `item`as parameter, no need to say that `item` will contain the inputs values?

**Here is the controller part**

```js
app.controller('projectController', ['$scope', '$folders', function($scope, $folders)
{
    $scope.create = function(item)
    {
        f = new $folders(item);
        f.$save(function(data,headers)
                {
                   alert('SAVED');
                },
                function(err,headers)
                {
                    alert('FAILED');
                });
    };
}]);
```

`$scope.create` is the action that will be called by `ng-submit`, `item` is the `item` parameter from the form as well, so you'll find stuff inside such as `item.description`.

`Folders` is the service object we talked about earlier.